# How to integrate forum into application?

Tags: android

I have a website that has a forum with users. I would like to integrate this functionality into my application? How would i go about doing this? If anyone has some instructions to start with that will be great. Or a tutorial some where.

Comment: The first question to make if it's worth the time. Another thing to add is what do you mean with "integration"?

Comment: the ability for users to actually post stuff and read the forum from inside the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a webview and try to make a mobile friendly version of your forum. You can also call the web browser.
It will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I know this [app forum sdk](http://www.linkingcell.com) that provide a native library and bundles to enable a forum in your app. Much faster and quicker response than webview.